# Need help to create table using Div instead of td?

Tags: html, css

Hi I want some help for creating tabular data using `div` instead of `td`. I am not expert in coding.

Result should be: (3 columns and 3 rows)

Moreover if I want more rows what will be exact code. And how can I put all these code (`css` and `html`)?

Comment: Is there any reason for that? I know it's recommended not using tables for laying out a page, but if you have tabular data, just use a table

Comment: http://ajaxian.com/archives/display-table

Comment: @Mohsen nothing probably as these are the basics.

Answer (score 0):

Hope it may helps you,

CSS:

```
   <style>
      .Rows {
            float:left;
            width:450px; 
        }

   </style>
```

HTML Section:

```
    <div>          
        <div class="Rows" >1st content here</div>
        <div class="Rows" >2nd content here</div>
        <div class="Rows">3rd content here</div>
    </div>
```